# What to use instead of two include?'s?

Tags: ruby

What is the simpler way of below ruby condition? What can I use instead of two `include?`

```
str1="str"
str2="sss"
string='string'

puts "yes" if (string.include?(str1) or string.include?(str2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
puts "yes" if string[str1] || string[str2]
```

But how about:

```
puts "yes" if [str1,str2].any?{|s| string[s]}
```

or even:

```
puts "yes" if string[/#{str1}|#{str2}/]
```

Comment: I like the second option the best because I can nicely and quickly read the strings that are part of the condition. Where can I read more about this kind of comparison `string[str2]`? What is the name for it?

Comment: That is String's [] method and you can read about it here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: You probably wanted `/#{str1}|#{str2}/` instead of `/#{str1}|#{str1}/`, didn't you?

Comment: @Michael - yes that's right thanks, feel free to edit my typos

Comment: The 3rd proposal works only as long as neither of the search strings contain meta-characters. `'foo'[/#{'.'}|#{','}/]` yields `'f'`.